# Boost DLL naming - Custom 'layouts'

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940249/boost-how-bjam-constructs-a-library-name), is there any way to specify a custom DLL naming layout when building boost?

It'd be nice if you could use some short of magic-variable naming format like "lib%name-%variation-%mt" to generate "libboost_chrono-debug-multithread.dll" (as an example), so you can re-arrange and remove/include just the information you want. Does such a boost configuration method exist?