# find_package of cmake cannot find boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969280/find-package-doesnt-detect-boost-on-windows-cmake) and made a CMakeLists.txt with following data:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
SET(TARGET integrity_scanner)
message("\nBuilding ${TARGET}")
project (${TARGET})
if (UNIX)
    message(STATUS "Setting GCC flags")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g3 -Wall -O0")
else()
    message(STATUS "Setting MSVC flags")
    #set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /EHc-")
endif ()

include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/boost_1_55_0_dyn)
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS thread)

SET(SOURCE
  IntegrityScanner.cpp
)

SET(HEADERS
  IntegrityScanner.h ../BaseApplication.hpp 
)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DDLL_EXPORTS)
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)

    include_directories("..\\..\\..\\ext_library\\zmq\\zeromq-4.0.3\\include")
    include_directories("..\\..\\..\\ext_library\\zmq\\czmq\\czmq-2.1.0\\include")
    link_directories("..\\..\\..\\ext_library\\zmq\\zeromq-4.0.3\\lib\\Win32\\Debug")
    link_directories("..\\..\\..\\ext_library\\zmq\\czmq\\czmq-2.1.0\\lib\\Win32\\DebugDLL")

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_library(${TARGET} SHARED ${SOURCE} ${HEADERS})
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} czmq libzmq)
else()
    message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND False")
endif()
```

Even though I have set **BOOST_ROOT** , it fails and gives the **Boost Found False** Message. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I have found that setting **Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS** to **OFF** is resolving the issue. But I have to have it **ON**. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason why this code is not working. As I am giving value **ON** to **Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS**, the result is that **find_package** will look for ***libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_55*** , which it will not find because building boost will give **shared** libraries as stated in this [link](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/linkage.html). Refer to pic below:
[image: Boost default linking]

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure needs to look like this:

```
c:/boost/boost_1_55_0
```

and BOOST_ROOT is an environment variable set to c:/boost