# How to find Boost filesystem library compiled with VS 2017 with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I have compiled Boost from source with Visual Studio 2017, and I'm using CMake 3.9.3 to find it with the following command in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
```

I'm invoking CMake like this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..
    -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\Users\emlai\src\libs\boost_1_65_0"
    -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="C:\Users\emlai\src\libs\boost_1_65_0\lib64-msvc-15.0"
```

I get the following message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1902 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.0

  Boost include path: C:/Users/emlai/src/libs/boost_1_65_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_filesystem

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  build/cmake-modules/FindSDL2.cmake:173 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/emlai/src/zenith/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/emlai/src/zenith/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The output of `dir C:\Users\emlai\src\libs\boost_1_65_0\lib64-msvc-15.0` shows that the filesystem libraries are in place.

I have tried all of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20969280/3425536), but without success. The same happens with the prebuilt Boost libraries downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.65.1/).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are the libraries x86 or x64?  Is the application looking for them x86 or x64?

Comment: @BenVoigt x64, but never mind, got it working. Had to specify the `Boost_COMPILER`  variable for CMake.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to pass `-DBoost_COMPILER="-vc141"` to CMake to make it work (`-vc141` being the same string as in the Boost library filenames).