# CMAKE - Could't find boost

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a problem with Cmake. Every library i want to configure and generate it shows me:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230
  (message):   Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system serialization)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) 
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)  
  CMake/HighFiveTargetDeps.cmake:27 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (include)
```

I have no idea what should I do. Right now Im trying to generate HighFive library for C++ and it shows me the same problem like in Shark library, Shogun library, Opencv, Eigen, Xtensor... Any idea what should I do? I'll be glad for every answer.

Comment: You need to install the Boost library in the correct way.

Comment: Please add multi line error messages as a code block; with quotes line breaks may not be perserved making the error hard to read in addition to interpreting some things as markdown... Unfortunately the line breaks were are already ignored when adding the citation block in the question making it difficult to restore the output you copied from the console

Comment: How have you installed boost? Assuming you built boost yourself, you should have used `.\\b2.exe ... install` resulting in a directory containing 2 subdirs in the directory set as prefix when installing boost: `include` and `lib` the `lib` dir should contain the dlls and import libs as well as a subdir `cmake` with one subdirectory per component. You may need to pass the boost install prefix via `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` during the configuration. Perhaps using the `--debug-find` option may yield additional info, should the above fail.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the project you are trying to compile requires the Boost include libraries. Did you install them? If not, you need to install Boost first.

Then you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969280/find-package-doesnt-detect-boost-on-windows-cmake), which has a similar problem in my opinion. The accepted answer explained the following system variables were added (please adapt your paths and version numbers):

```
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR    C:\SDKs\boost_1_58_0\
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR    C:\SDKs\boost_1_58_0\lib64-msvc-12.0
BOOST_ROOT          C:\SDKs\boost_1_58_0\boost
```